# Need an algorithm to manipulate array structure in javascript

Tags: javascript

In javascript, here is my start array:

```
[{
   name: 'aaa',
   value: 1
 },
 {
   name: 'bbb',
   value: 0
 },
 {
   name: 'bbb',
   value: 1
}]
```

I want to transform it into this array as result:

```
[{
   name: 'aaa',
   value: 1
 },
 {
   name: 'bbb',
   value: [0, 1]
 }]
```

I need a good and simple algorithm to do this

Comment: Do you want to modify the array in-place or to create a new one?

Comment: What you should really drive for is a situation where `value` is always an array; even if it's length 1. It'll make things a **hell** of a lot easier.

Comment: @Matt I bet the example included that case specifically to show how the algorithm should handle 1-value cases.

Comment: @Max: I guessed that as well, that's why I'm recommending an alternate algorithm :). Trying to use the array later down the line and not knowing whether you'll be retrieving an array or number will be a PITA.

Comment: @Max: Even Javascript's `Array.splice` function **always** returns an array even when there was just one element removed...

Comment: @Matt: it's an array generated by Jquery serializeArray(). When you got a multiple select element, it will generate like that. This algorithm will help to group all the data together. If you convert all to array, on server side, you can't know whether an element is a multiple element or not.

Comment: @ThanhTrung: Ahh, that makes sense. Sounds like an acceptable use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
var array = [{
   name: 'aaa',
   value: 1
 },
 {
   name: 'bbb',
   value: 0
 },
 {
   name: 'bbb',
   value: 1
}];

var map = {};    
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var name = array[i].name;
  if (map[name] === undefined) {
    map[name] = [];
  }
  map[name].push(array[i].value);
}

var result = [];
for(var key in map) {
  var value = map[key];
  result.push({
    name: key, 
    value: value.length === 1 ? value[0] : value
  });
}
```

Easiest way is to create a map to keep track of which names are used. Then convert this map back to an array of objects.

If you want to use Arrays for `value` then change it to:

```
result.push({
  name: key, 
  value: value
});
```

Comment: This solution does not satisfy the requirements. 1-value case will result in `value: [1]` not `value: 1` as was requested.

Comment: You've beaten me to it with practically the same solution. :)

Comment: You even made the same mistake :)

Comment: @Jan: Which one? You mean the requirement? Well I think that's an *added complexity* requirements anyway because it needs checking afterwards. It's much better to keep all values as arrays to avoid unnecessary code checks afterwards.

Comment: @Jan: And basically we both implemented first poster's pseudo code. Any of us could actually come up with a solution that manipulates original array, but it would also need intermediate associative object with array index to original object. Code wouldn't be simpler. Just different.

Answer (score 1):

here's pseudocode for simplest implementation

```
hash = {}
for(pair in array) {
    hash[pair.name] ||= []
    hash[pair.name] << pair.value
}

result = []
for(k, v in hash) {
    result << {name: k, value: v}
}
```

Comment: What does (hash[pair.name] << pair.value) mean?

Comment: There are syntax errors. Javascript doesn't accept hash[pair.name] ||= [] and hash[pair.name] << pair.value (copied pasted exactly like that in my editor)

Comment: apparently because i gave you pseudocode. you have to figure out the details on your own. btw ||= is assignment operation which only executes if left-hand value is empty.

Comment: Ok thx, I'm not good with pseudo-code anyway. Your code looks like the codes above.

Answer (score 0):

### This function does the trick

```
function consolidate(var arrayOfObjects)    
{
    // create a dictionary of values first
    var dict = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfObjects.length; i++)
    {
        var n = arrayOfObjects[i].name;
        if (!dict[n])
        {
            dict[n] = [];
        }
        dict[n].push(arrayOfObjects[i].value);
    }

    // convert dictionary to array again        
    var result = [];
    for(var key in dict)
    {
        result.push({
            name: key,
            value: dict[key].length == 1 ? dict[key][0] : dict[key]
        });
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution:

```
function convert(arr) {
    var res = [];
    var map = {};

    for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        var arrObj = arr[i];
        var oldObj = map[arrObj.name];
        if (oldObj == undefined) {
            oldObj = {name:arrObj.name, value:arrObj.value};
            map[arrObj.name] = oldObj;
            res.push(oldObj);
        } else {
            if( typeof oldObj.value === 'number' ) {
                oldObj.value = [oldObj.value];
            }
            oldObj.value.push(arrObj.value);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

In theory it should work a bit faster and use less memory. Basically it creates a result array and a map which is an index for the same array (no duplicate objects). So it fills the result in one iteration instead of two and does not need to convert map to array (which saves several CPU cycles :P ).

**Added:**
Here is a variation of that function in case `value: [1]` is acceptable:

```
function convert(arr) {
    var res = [];
    var map = {};

    for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        var arrObj = arr[i];
        var oldObj = map[arrObj.name];
        if (oldObj == undefined) {
            oldObj = {name:arrObj.name, value:[arrObj.value]};
            map[arrObj.name] = oldObj;
            res.push(oldObj);
        } else {
            oldObj.value.push(arrObj.value);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```